# Adiabatic turning on of coupling constant in simulation of $\phi^4$ theories in the JLP algorithm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, research-level, simulations, quantum-computer

In the [Quantum Algorithms for Quantum Field Theories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3633) by Jordan, Lee and Preskill they have devised an efficient algorithm to simulate  $\phi^4$ theories. Given by the Lagrangian density $$\mathcal{L}(\varphi)=\frac{1}{2} [\partial^\mu \varphi \partial_\mu \varphi -m^2 \varphi^2] -\frac{1}{4}\lambda \varphi^4. $$

During the simulation they prepare the state and then turn on the coupling parameter $\lambda$ adiabatically (Edit: The simulation itself is not adiabatic, it uses the Suzuki-Trotter methods).  I am confused by this step for two reasons

- Why do they need to start with the solvable Gaussian theory and then turn on the coupling adiabatically later?
- If this adiabatic turning on is necessary then why is it not done for all quantum algorithms? For instance take the Grover search. We need to apply the Oracle operator and the Grover reflection operator in an alternating manner. Doing that on a quantum system will require you to switch between two Hamiltonians. Wouldn't this time dependent switching between Hamiltonians induce undesired transformations in the algorithm if not done carefully? But such considerations are never discussed while talking about the algorithm.

Comment: I think to start simulate the evolution of H, they need to prepare an initial state. Does they ask the initial state should be the ground state of H, so they need an adiabatic process to achieve this from a simpler solvable H'?

Comment: I did not see this is a part of adiabatic Grover search implementation since there, the initial state can be easily prepared. I think the JLP is special on this point, the adiabatic process is only used to prepare the starting state of the later simulation.

Comment: I don't think they start at the ground state of the $\phi^4$ theory as  the algorithm is supposed to simulate general scattering processes in the theory (I am confused about this). They construct Gaussians  using the Kitaev-Webb algorithm and then turn on the coupling.

Comment: My concern about  Grovers algorithm is not about preparing the initial state, but the  transitions that may be caused by alternating between the Oracle and Grover operators.

Comment: According to their description, given a proper initial state, it seems that the simulation of scattering process is not based on adiabatic process, so the adiabatic process is only used to prepare the initial state. Not sure if this is right.  After turning on the coupling adiabatically, should the system stay in a ground state of a $H(\lambda)$ ($\lambda$ a factor to control the coupling) till the initial state is prepared?